# lexical error in string/character literal at character '\57441'

Tags: haskell, ghc

GHC gives me an error with a special unicode character. The character is the "mute" symbol from font-awesome.

```
putStrLn ""
```

The error: `lexical error in string/character literal at character '\57441'`

I found this ticket where a similar behavior is described (https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/5518). The ticket says it should be fixed with ghc > 7.2.1. I am using ghc 8.0.2 and it does not work anyways.

Does anybody know how to bypass this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to write it as a Unicode escape, decimal `"\57441"` or hexadecimal `"\xE061"`.

Comment: I really thought i had tried this but i must have done '\57441' instead (as the compiler gives that as an error) or something... Thank you so much.